# Skinning a link button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Here is the modified code i have done. Here i have given the skin class & selection color.

latest code

```
<mx:LinkButton label="home" styleName="Helvetica22555555" id="homeBtn" fontSize="14" color="#ffffff"
                       useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" 
                       skin="{com.firstplanet.utils.ULinkButtonSkin}" toggle="true" selectionColor="0xC0D3E2"/>
        <mx:LinkButton label="course" styleName="Helvetica22555555" id="link"  fontSize="14" color="#ffffff"
                       skin="{com.firstplanet.utils.ULinkButtonSkin}" selectionColor="0xC0D3E2"/>
        <mx:LinkButton label="dashboard" styleName="Helvetica22555555" fontSize="14" color="#ffffff"
                       skin="{com.firstplanet.utils.ULinkButtonSkin}" toggle="true" selectionColor="0xC0D3E2"/>
        <mx:LinkButton label="logout" styleName="Helvetica22555555" fontSize="14" color="#ffffff"
                       useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true"
                       skin="{com.firstplanet.utils.ULinkButtonSkin}" toggle="true" selectionColor="0xC0D3E2"/>
```

and the skin class i have used as per below ansers

```
 package com.firstplanet.utils
 {
import mx.skins.halo.LinkButtonSkin;

public class ULinkButtonSkin extends LinkButtonSkin
{
    public function ULinkButtonSkin()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void
    {
        var cornerRadius:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
        var selectionColor:uint = getStyle("selectionColor");
        graphics.clear();

        switch (name)
        {           
            case "selectedUpSkin":
            case "selectedOverSkin":
            case "selectedDownSkin":
            {
                drawRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, cornerRadius, selectionColor, 1);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(w, h);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But its not working. If i will select one button then others are also getting highlighted with it.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
<local:ULinkButton label="Red Link Button" skin="ULinkButtonSkin" toggle="true" selectionColor="0xFF0000"/>
```

Skin for changing background color:

```
package
{
import mx.skins.halo.LinkButtonSkin;

public class ULinkButtonSkin extends LinkButtonSkin
{
    public function ULinkButtonSkin()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void
    {
        var cornerRadius:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
        var selectionColor:uint = getStyle("selectionColor");
        graphics.clear();

        switch (name)
        {           
            case "selectedUpSkin":
            case "selectedOverSkin":
            case "selectedDownSkin":
            {
                drawRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, cornerRadius, selectionColor, 1);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(w, h);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay then how can i highlight the button after selection ?

Comment: It seems I've got you task wrong ) So, you want to change button color in selected state?

Comment: yes i want to highlight the link button when it got selected.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the custom _LinkButtonSkin_ programmatic skin.

Comment: But its not working if there is so many link buttons no link bar only buttons then this method fails i dont know where is the problem if i will select one button then other button are getting selected.

Comment: can you add the mxml of the case, when it's not working?